# Make gradient border for each angle of circle

Tags: javascript

[image]

```js
var arraySpin = ['#15b98e','#ba3ee9','#f7c951','#f83757','#15b98e','#ba3ee9','#f7c951','#f83757'];
var w = 200, h = 200, r = 100;
var svg = d3.select('#circle-split')
  .append('svg')
  .data([arraySpin])
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

// create group for element
var container = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + (w / 2) + ',' + (h / 2) + ')');
var vis = container.append('g');
var widthWin = 65, heightWin = 65;

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) { return 1; });

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcColor = vis.selectAll('g.color')
  .data(pie)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'color');
arcColor.append('path')
  .attr('fill', function (d, i) { return arraySpin[i]; })
  .attr('d', function (d) { return arc(d); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle-split"></div>
```

I use d3.v3.min.js to make a circle like pizza, but how to make border gradient for each angle?
I need it for lucky wheel.

Comment: Which border? The outer circle, or the straight lines coming from the center? And how wide should the gradient be?

Comment: The border that I drew by hand. red part will border red (gradient), width about 5px. not outer circle, border between other part of circle

Comment: You need to play with   .attr('stroke', 'red')      .attr('stroke-width', '5px')

Comment: In case it wouldn't be possible with SVG or CSS: would an image be an acceptable alternative? Would a canvas drawing be an acceptable alternative?